# not Display text

Tags: php, image

```
<?php

header ("Content-type: image/pjpeg");
$string = "manujagadeesh!!!";                                             
$font  =8;
$width  = ImageFontWidth($font)* strlen($string) ;
$height = ImageFontHeight($font) ;

$im = ImageCreateFromjpeg("sachin.jpg");
$x=100;
$y=200;
$background_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 255, 255); //white background
$text_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 0, 0,0);//black text
imagestring ($im, $font, $x, $y,  $string, $text_color);
imagejpeg ($im);
?>
```

this is the  add text to image in php

wen we inclue the my html page the text is not displaying

for eg

```
<?php

header ("Content-type: image/pjpeg");
$string = "manujagadeesh!!!";                                             
$font  =8;
$width  = ImageFontWidth($font)* strlen($string) ;
$height = ImageFontHeight($font) ;

$im = ImageCreateFromjpeg("sachin.jpg");
$x=100;
$y=200;
$background_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 255, 255); //white background
$text_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 0, 0,0);//black text
imagestring ($im, $font, $x, $y,  $string, $text_color);
imagejpeg ($im);
?>

hi welcome
```

couldn't see the hi wlecome

Answer (score 2):

You can't output both content of type `image/jpeg` and `text/html` from the same PHP script.  Move your image generation code to another file eg `stringImage.php` and use the following code to include it:

```
<img src="stringImage.php" />
hi welcome
```

As long as `stringImage.php` only outputs the image data with the correct content type, and nothing else, you should get your expected result.

Comment: @tismon if the answer fixed your issue, mark it as accepted by clicking the big tick to the left